# How to select all and copy content of .txt file

Tags: copy-paste, text-editor

I have a .txt file on my Android phone. How can I copy it's content to the clipboard, so that I can paste it elsewhere?

When I open the .txt file and long press, I only get "Paste". That is in "DB Text Editor". I also tried installing "Simple Notepad" and opening the file with that, but I still cannot "Select All" or "Copy".

My phone is running Android 4.4.2.

Comment: can you paste a screenshot?

Comment: Install [color note](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.socialnmobile.dictapps.notepad.color.note) and open the text file with it. You can then copy portion/ complete text. I have been using it earlier in KitKat

Comment: [clipper+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fi.rojekti.clipper) is another option. Whatever text you highlight and copy is automatically copied into this app and you can paste it. I haven't used this on KitKat thigh

Comment: Even [Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer)'s built-in text editor can handle that - grab it if you also need a decent file explorer.

Comment: Or you could use hackers keyboard. Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First double tape on a line with text, then move cursors and select the text you want to copy[image]

Comment: Yes, double-tapping on a word (not in the empty space) worked. Why have such basic things as "select all", which were obvious 25 years ago, become so convoluted? ...